# iOS: Get SubView width after constraints in a separate UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I currently have a storyboard linked to a ViewController (.h and .m). Inside the storyboard (Main View), I have created another UIView that takes about half of the top screen. I have assigned that to a custom Class. The custom class has a .h .m and XIB file. A specific code fragment in my custom class contains the following:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self){
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"myXIB" owner:self options:nil];

    NSLog(@"Width before: %f",self.bounds.size.width);
    NSLog(@"Height After: %f",self.bounds.size.height);

    //[self setNeedsLayout];
    //[self layoutIfNeeded];

    UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, 44)];
    [self.view addSubview:searchBar];


    CGRect newFrame = self.view.frame;
    newFrame.size.width = self.bounds.size.width;
    newFrame.size.height = self.bounds.size.height;
    [self.view setFrame:newFrame];

    [self addSubview:self.view];
}
return self;
}
```

The code currently creates a UISearchBar and add its to the sub view in my story board. My problem is related to calculating the width. The UISearchBar takes the argument for the width to be:

```
self.bounds.size.width
```

This calculates the frame drawed in the storyboard. However because the UIView inside my story board has constraints, the frame is not the final width. E.g. If i drawed 200px width in the story board, my code will retrieve the 200 and set the UISearch bar as 200 width. But in theory, the constraints will kick in and set the width to the size of the device e.g. 600px. So my question is, how can I find the updated width?

I have tried:

```
[self setNeedsLayout];
[self layoutIfNeeded];
```

They did not seem to work. Please can you suggest ideas?

Comment: did you try doing it in layoutSubviews

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    NSLog(@"Width before: %f",self.bounds.size.width);
    NSLog(@"Height After: %f",self.bounds.size.height);

}
```

This should give you the actual size